# In GHCi, can I use the result of the previous expression?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm doing some experimenting in GHCi, and I have a moderately long running (5 minutes) operation that I'm trying to tune. The result starts printing out partway through, and I can often tell that my algorithm isn't correctly tuned yet after 1 minute or less, so I cancel the operation. But when I do find the result, I want to allow it continue to the end, then use it afterwards as well. If I assign it when I start it, though, I can't see it as it processes. Is there any way I can access the result of the previous expression entered into GHCi?

Comment: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/getting-started.html#x_U2

Answer (score 29, accepted):

GHCi has the special variable `it` for this purpose.

```
Prelude> 1
  1
Prelude> it
  1
```

The reason for this, as explained in the [GHCi docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html) is that non-IO expressions behave like so

```
someExpr ==> let it = someExpr
             print it
```

If `someExpr` were IO then we'd have

```
it <- someExpr
print it
```

so `it` should always be the result of your previous expression.